# JQuery draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to create my first JQuery-based webpage. 
At the moment there is a little problem with my draggable div.
I am able to move it and it works well but I am able to move it out of my screen. Is there a code like `maxleft=0px`?

#### JQUERY:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#card" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
  });
</script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="card" class="card">
     <img src="https://pic.jpg" class="profil-pic" alt="img" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Okay, I gave my body an ID. Now my JQuery looks like this:<div class="header"> The right side of the screen is okay but I am still able to movie it out on the left side.

Comment: That's a solution. Add parent element to div and attach `containment` attribute to parent!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n210zvwp/

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in the css-file. It works now! ty  j08691 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need give boundry div in which area it can be move.

```
 $("#card").draggable({
            axis: "x",
            containment: 'body'
        });
```